# The trait `A` is not implemented for the type `A`

Tags: rust, traits

I am trying to use a trait that has a function that takes a closure as argument, and then use it on a trait object.

```
trait A {
    fn f<P>(&self, p: P) where P: Fn() -> ();
}

struct B {
    a: Box<A>
}

impl B {
    fn c(&self) {
        self.a.f(|| {});
    }
}
```

This snippet generates the following error:

```
the trait `A` is not implemented for the type `A` [E0277]
```

The version of `rustc` is `rustc 1.0.0-beta.3 (5241bf9c3 2015-04-25) (built 2015-04-25)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that method `f` is not object-safe because it is generic, and hence it can't be called on a trait object. You will have to force its users to pass boxed closure:

```
trait A {
    fn f(&self, p: Box<Fn() -> ()>);
}
```

I wonder why Rust allows `Box<A>` in the first place, I would expect an error there. And this particular error is really misleading. I would file a bug about this.

Alternatively, you can discard trait objects in favor of regular bounded generics, though it is not always possible.

Comment: Isn't `Box<TraitA>` legal in Rust?

Comment: @DanielFath: the point is that `Box<A>` is approximately useless because `A` is not object safe—you can’t actually *do* anything with it.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Interesting. Can you point me to more resource on what object safe means and what is and isn't object safe?

Comment: Here's a blog post on the topic by huon: http://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/01/object-safety/

Comment: Note that you can actually use a reference (`&`) instead of a `Box` if you want to use the stack instead of the heap. I.e. `fn f(&self, p: &Fn() -> ());`. Apparently this is still called a 'boxed closure', despite not using a `Box`. In this context, 'boxed' just means it's a pointer type.