# Trait `x` is not implemented for the type `x`

Tags: generics, compiler-errors, rust, traits

When compiling the following code:

```
trait RenderTarget {}

struct RenderWindow;
impl RenderTarget for RenderWindow {}

trait Drawable {
    fn draw<RT: RenderTarget>(&self, target: &mut RT);
}

fn main() {
    let mut win = RenderWindow;
    let mut vec: Vec<Box<Drawable>> = Vec::new();

    for e in &vec {
        e.draw(&mut win);
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
error: the trait `Drawable` is not implemented for the type `Drawable` [E0277]
src/main.rs:15         e.draw(&mut win);
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What is the error message trying to tell? Also, how to fix it?

There's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30055356/3425536) but the solution there was to modify the trait `A` (which corresponds to `Drawable` in my case), but that's not possible here since `Drawable` is from an external library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** fixed object safety rules to the 1.0 version of them. Namely, by-value `self` makes method object-unsafe no longer.

This error happens because of [object safety](http://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/01/object-safety/).

In order to be able to create a trait object out of a trait, the trait must be object-safe. A trait is object-safe if both of these statements hold:

1. it does not have `Sized` requirement, as in `trait Whatever: Sized {}`;
2. all its methods are object-safe.

A method is object-safe if both of these statements are true:

1. it has `where Self: Sized` requirement, as in `fn method() where Self: Sized`;
2. none of the following statements holds:

   1. this method mentions `Self` in their signature in any form, even under a reference, except associated types;
   2. this method is static;
   3. this method is generic.

These restrictions are in fact fairly natural if you think more of them.

Remember that when values are made into trait objects, actual information of their type is erased, including their size. Therefore, trait objects can only be used through a reference. References (or other smart pointers, like `Box` or `Rc`), when applied to trait objects, become "fat pointers" - along with the pointer to the value, they also contain a pointer to the virtual table for that value.

Because trait objects can only be used through a pointer, by-value `self` methods can't be called on them - you'd need the actual value in order to call such methods. This was a violation of object safety at one point, which meant that traits with such methods couldn't be made trait objects, however, even before 1.0 the rules had been tweaked to allow by-value `self` methods on trait objects. These methods still can't be called, though, due to the reason described above. There are reasons to expect that in the future this restriction will be lifted because it currently leads to some quirks in the language, for example, the inability to call `Box<FnOnce()>` closures.

`Self` can't be used in methods which should be called on trait objects precisely because trait objects have their actual type erased, but in order to call such methods the compiler would need to know this erased type.

Why static methods can't be called on trait objects, I guess, is obvious - static methods by definition "belong" to the trait itself, not to the value, so you need to know the concrete type implementing the trait to call them. More concretely, regular methods are dispatched through a virtual table stored inside a trait object, but static methods do not have a receiver, so they have nothing to dispatch on, and for this reason they can't be stored in a virtual table. Thus they are uncallable without knowing the concrete type.

Generic trait methods can't be called for another reason, more technical than logical, I think. In Rust generic functions and methods are implemented through monomorphization - that is, for each instantiation of a generic function with a concrete set of type parameters the compiler generate a separate function. For the language user it looks like that they're calling a generic function; but on the lowest level for each set of type parameters there is a separate copy of the function, specialized to work for the instantiated types.

Given this approach, in order to call generic methods on a trait object you would need its virtual table to contain pointers to *virtually each and every possible* instantiation of the generic method for all possible types, which is, naturally, impossible because it would require infinite number of instantiations. And so calling generic methods on trait objects is disallowed.

If `Drawable` is an external trait, then you're stuck - it is impossible to do what you want, that is, to call `draw()` on each item in a heterogeneous collection. If your set of drawables is statically known, you can create a separate collection for each drawable type or, alternatively, create your own `enum` which would contain a variant for each drawable type you have. Then you can implement `Drawable` for the enum itself, which would be fairly straightforward.

Comment: "you would need its virtual table to contain pointers to virtually each and every possible instantiation of the generic method for all possible types, which [...] would require infinite number of instantiations." No it wouldn't - there are only a finite number of types and only a small subset actually get used in the code. It would seem to be possible to statically detect these, if not worth the cost.

Comment: "there are only a finite number of types" really? There is infinite amount of types, and here is a proof. If you start from these propositions: `i32 in Types`, `for all T. Option<T> in Types` (which are obviously true), you can easily derive that all of `i32`, `Option<i32>`, `Option<Option<i32>>` and so on are types. Therefore the set of types is infinite because we just have found its infinite subset. Of course, the set of types *actually used* in a program is finite, but finding it and generating methods for each generic trait for them and then removing unused ones would be very hard indeed.

Comment: I'd also add that it looks like it poses some problems with interoperability. Suppose a trait with a generic method is defined in one crate, and its trait objects are used in the same crate. It would need to generate some kind of virtual table for this crate. Now this crate is used by another crate which also uses trait objects for the same trait, but with different type parameters for its method. Now we have two incompatible virtual tables, and so trait objects created in the first and the second crate are not compatible. Things get even funnier, it seems, if we start using shared libraries.

Comment: "there are only a finite number of types" → Yes. Are there an infinite number of humans? You've described the space of possible types, but to Rust `Option<Option<Option<i32>>>` isn't a type until you monomorphise it. As such, finding all of the types would be as simple as looking in whatever table Rust uses for caching things.

Comment: "I'd also add that it looks like it poses some problems with interoperability." Indeed, I agree it's not practical.

Comment: There *is* an infinite number of types which can be described by the type system because the type system is a mathematical model. There is nothing which prevents you from writing out a new type if you have some concrete and generic types already, except from time and memory required to do so, and this is a (one of many possible) definition of a "countably infinite set". In each **concrete** program there is indeed only a finite subset of types used, but it does not make the whole set of types finite. And I don't understand your "human" analogy, sorry. These are conceptually different things.

Comment: When you say "every possible instantiation of the generic method for all possible types" it's pointless to consider types not defined by the program. Whether or not you want to say "all types" is in context of the type system or in context of usage (as another example, is "all programs" an infinite set?) is arguing about semantics, which is silly.  Rather, we should be considering what actually matters to the argument you're making, which is the finite set of instantiated types.

Comment: Well, I disagree that arguing about semantics is silly. I'm a mathematician, and such things seems important to me :) BTW "all programs" is also an infinite set, while "all existing/written programs" is large but finite. Anyway, I do think that this arguing is rather pointless, so I suggest to conclude it here.

Answer (score 3):

I refer to Vladimir's excellent answer which explains Object's safety, however I am afraid than in the middle of the discussion the concrete problem at hand was forgotten.

As Vladimir mentions, the issue is that a method generic over types (generic over lifetimes is fine) renders the trait it belongs to unusable for run-time polymorphism; this, in Rust, is called Object Safety.

The simplest fix, therefore, is to remove the generic parameter of the method!

```
trait RenderTarget {}

struct RenderWindow;
impl RenderTarget for RenderWindow {}

trait Drawable {
    fn draw(&self, target: &mut RenderTarget);
}

fn main() {
    let mut win = RenderWindow;
    let mut vec: Vec<Box<Drawable>> = Vec::new();

    for e in &vec {
        e.draw(&mut win);
    }
}
```

The main difference between:

```
fn draw<RT: RenderTarget>(&self, target: &mut RT)
```

and

```
fn draw(&self, target: &mut RenderTarget)
```

is that the latter requires `RenderTarget` to be Object Safe too as it is now used in a run-time polymorphism situation (so, no static method, no generic method, no `Self`, ...).

Another (more technical) difference is that the former is "monorphised" at compile-time (that is `RT` is substituted with the real type and all relevant optimizations applied) whereas the latter is not (and so, no such optimizations occur).

Answer (score 2):

If you're stuck with what you're given, there are two options you could try.

In this case, you can't, but if you were given an unsized `RenderTarget`

```
trait Drawable {
    fn draw<RT: RenderTarget + ?Sized>(&self, target: &mut RT);
}
```

you could implement

```
trait DrawableDynamic {
    fn draw(&self, target: &mut RenderTarget);
}

impl<T: Drawable> DrawableDynamic for T {
    fn draw(&self, target: &mut RenderTarget) {
        Drawable::draw(self, target)
    }
}
```

to redirect the types you're given to an object-safe dynamically dispatched alternative. It looks like such a change could be made upstream, since you can't really *use* the fact that `RT` is sized.

The other doesn't allow you to put arbitrary `Drawable`s in your `Vec`, but should work without allowing unsized types upstream. This is to use an enum to wrap the possible values of the vector:

```
enum AllDrawable {
    Square(Square),
    Triangle(Triangle)
}

impl Drawable for AllDrawable {
    fn draw<RT: RenderTarget>(&self, target: &mut RT) {
        match *self { 
            AllDrawable::Square(ref x) => x.draw(target),
            AllDrawable::Triangle(ref x) => x.draw(target),
        }
    }
}
```

One might want to add `From` implementations and such; you might find it easier if using [`wrapped_enum!`](https://hoverbear.github.io/raft/wrapped_enum/index.html) which will automatically implement those for you.