# Trait with methods that take generic parameters

Tags: rust

I'm building a webapp in Rust and trying to implement basic Rails-style database migrations for managing my database. In my code, Migration is a trait with up and down methods to apply and roll back the migration. Each individual database migration is a struct that implements the Migration trait.

I started out with this version of the Migration trait, and it compiles fine:

```
pub trait Migration : Display {
    fn up(&self, connection: &postgres::Connection) -> postgres::Result<()>;
    fn down(&self, connection: &postgres::Connection) -> postgres::Result<()>;
}
```

But ideally I'd like to allow the caller to pass in either a transaction object or a raw connection object to run the migration. The Postgres crate supports this by providing the `GenericConnection` trait which both connections and transactions implement. So I refactored my Migration trait to this:

```
pub trait Migration : Display {
    fn up<T: postgres::GenericConnection>(&self, connection: &T) -> postgres::Result<()>;
    fn down<T: postgres::GenericConnection>(&self, connection: &T) -> postgres::Result<()>;
}
```

But now when I compile, any code that tries to make use of a Migration generates the error `the trait db::migrations::migration::Migration is not implemented for the type db::migrations::migration::Migration`. For example, I have a struct that keeps track of all my migrations:

```
pub struct MigrationIndex {
    /// all database migrations, in order from first to last
    migrations: Vec<Box<Migration>>
}
```

And it compiles fine with the first version of the `Migration` trait, and fails with the error above when using the version of `Migration` with generics. Am I using generics in traits wrong?

Comment: Ideally, you should create an [MCVE](/help/mcve) that doesn't require us to know the postgres crate in and out. Something that runs on [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) is the best.

Comment: My [attempt at an MCVE](http://is.gd/WNlcSW) doesn't seem to have the same problem you relate.

Comment: I went ahead and built up a simple demonstration on the Rust Playground, but you're right--it doesn't show the error I'm seeing. I guess I don't even know what the underlying issue is, which makes this question unanswerable.

Comment: Keep on trying! Sometimes the act of building the MCVE helps you solve the problem yourself — then you can come back and help us understand ^_^.

Comment: Incidentally, this question has already been asked (and answered) a week ago. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081065/trait-x-is-not-implemented-for-the-type-x/). If it is indeed about your problem, we'll close this one as a duplicate. If not, try to explain the difference of your question from that question.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Good find, that was exactly it. Looks like I can't have generics in a trait that I'm using inside a Box.